# Errors with \bibentry with bibliography style that puts macro in bbl file

Tags: bibtex, bibentry

The following example works fine.  However, if `\bibliographystle{plainnat}` is replaced by `\bibliographystle{te}`, where `te.bst` is the style available at http://econtheory.org/technical/te.bst, then two errors are generated: "Undefined control sequence.   Hotelling, Harold (1929), \enquote ..." and "Undefined control sequence.   ...ding, Massachusetts. \bibAnnoteFile ...".

The problem seems to be that `\enquote` and `\bibAnnoteFile` are needed to format the reference, but are not supplied in time. (The bibliographystyle puts their definitions in the bbl file.)

Is there a simple solution?

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@article{HotellingEJ1929,
  author = {Hotelling, Harold},
  title = {Stability in competiton},
  journal = {Economic Journal},
  year = {1929},
  volume = {39},
  pages = {41-57}
}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

\nobibliography{mytestbib}

A full in-text cite of \bibentry{HotellingEJ1929}.

A regular citation of \cite{HotellingEJ1929}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\nobibliography` seems to be the problem

Comment: @Christian As far as I can see, `\bibentry` needs `\enquote` (and `\bibAnnoteFile`) to format the citation, and although `\enquote` is defined in the bbl file it appears only within the `bibliography` environment.  So reading the bbl file doesn't define `\enquote`.  I could add a definition of `\enquote` explicitly to the file, but then when the bibliography is output the error that `\enquote` is already defined will be generated.

Comment: @MartinJOsborne: Well, one way is to comment the definition of `\enquote` inside `te.bst` and use the package `csquotes` in your document. However, there is still this error with `\bibAnnoteFile`, I could not figure out why

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the problem (which is far from being perfect), each macro used within the `bibitems` of the `bbl` file needs to be made available to `bibentry` when the later is called in the code. The way I've been able to do this, is to make them global within the `Tex` file explicitly with `\global\def`.

However, for `\enquote`, this is different because the command is defined in the `bbl` directly, which as you noted, results in an "\enquote is already defined" error. To circumvent this issue, as noted by @ChristianHupfer, you can comment out those following two lines in the `te.bst` file:

```
%  write$ newline$
%  "\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}"
```

and add a definition of `\enquote` explicitly in the preamble of your `Tex` document (as you already said in a previous comment).

Here is a modified version of your MWE that works on my system without error (with the two lines listed above commented in the `te.bst` file):

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@article{HotellingEJ1929,
  author = {Hotelling, Harold},
  title = {Stability in competiton},
  journal = {Economic Journal},
  year = {1929},
  volume = {39},
  pages = {41-57}
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\bibliographystyle{te}
\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}
\global\def\bibAnnoteFile{}

\begin{document}

\nobibliography*

\noindent A full in-text cite of \bibentry{HotellingEJ1929}.

\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I experience a similar issue with my BST-files and found success changing the `\newcommand` macro to `\providecommand` in the BST-file.  Instead of:

```
write$ newline$
"\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}"
```

Try:

```
write$ newline$
"\providecommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}"
```

I cannot give a good explanation why one works and not the other, but it seems to be a more robust workaround than hacking your `main.tex` file.

Comment: This could work, provided the definition in the main document is the same as in the `.bbl` file (or somehow equivalent).